# Parse string to get href given attribute value

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I have a string with the following content:

```
var string = 
'<div class="product-info-inner-content clearfix ">\
    <a href="http://www.adidas.co.uk/ace-17_-purecontrol-firm-ground-boots/BB4314.html"\
      class="link-BB4314 product-link clearfix "\
      data-context="name:ACE 17+ Purecontrol Firm Ground Boots"\
      data-track="BB4314"\
      data-productname="ACE 17+ Purecontrol Firm Ground Boots"  tabindex="-1">\
        <span class="title">ACE 17+ Purecontrol Firm Ground Boots</span>\
        <span class="subtitle">Men Football</span>\
    </a>\
</div>';
```

I am trying to perform the JavaScript equivalent of the following Python code, in which uses beautiful soup to grab the URL of the div class element given a product code (i.e. in this case BB4314).

```
 is_listing = len(soup.findAll(name="div", attrs={"class": "product-tile"})) > 1
        if is_listing:
        # stuck from this part
        attrs = {"class": re.compile(r".*\bproduct-link\b.*"), "data-track": code} 
        url = soup.find(name="a", attrs=attrs)
        url = url["href"]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use DOM

```js
var string = '<div class="product-info-inner-content clearfix "><a href="http://www.adidas.co.uk/ace-17_-purecontrol-firm-ground-boots/BB4314.html" class="link-BB4314 product-link clearfix " data-context="name:ACE 17+ Purecontrol Firm Ground Boots" data-track="BB4314" data-productname="ACE 17+ Purecontrol Firm Ground Boots"  tabindex="-1"><span class="title">ACE 17+ Purecontrol Firm Ground Boots</span> <span class="subtitle">Men Football</span></a></div>',
  div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = string;
var href = div.querySelector("a.product-link").href,
  parts = href.split("/"),
  code = parts.pop().split(".")[0];
console.log(code)

console.log(div.querySelector("a.product-link").getAttribute("data-track"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this work in  case where the string looks like this: http://pastebin.com/ttpn6wth (i.e. parsing an entire web page).

Comment: Yes, but you could also get and parse the meta tag: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.adidas.co.uk/search?q=BB4314" />`

Comment: Thanks, but the meta tag takes me to the listing page, when in actual fact, I want the product page.

Comment: See the update for two ways of getting the code in the string you gave me

Comment: Why do you not use `class` selector to get `<a>` element? For example, if a different `<a>` element is at `[0]` at return value of `.getElementsByTagName("a")`?